# Manage the Win2008 routing table

Tags: windows, networking, routing, network-protocols, route

I have a networking issue 
As I have now two network cards and each one should connect to a specific network; one should be used to connect to the internet and the other one for intranet.

I want to manage the routing table as I think it will help me with this but I don't know if I do it wrong or it's not the way solve the problem ?!

Tech info :

I'm using win server 2008

Interface List

```
 23.....802.11 USB Wireless LAN Card
 10.....Intel(R) 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection
```

I need the Intel(R) 82567LM-3 one to connect to the intranet

To explain it clearly

my network like

```
network        Netmask         gateway           metric
 10.0.226.5       255.255.255.0   10.0.226.1           20   ---> for interface [10] that I need to use it for intranet



network        Netmask         gateway           metric
 192.168.1.2    255.255.255.0   192.168.1.1        30   --->  for interface [23] that I need to use it for internet
```

Comment: And I need to work on both networks together

Answer (score 2):

Adding a static route for that network is the correct way to do that.

You can add a route with the [route](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757323%28WS.10%29.aspx) command.

Example: `route add x.x.x.x MASK y.y.y.y  z.z.z.z METRIC m IF i`

Where:

`x.x.x.x` = The network that you want to route to.

`y.y.y.y` = The netmask for that network.

`z.z.z.z` = The gateway for that network.

`m` = metric for that route.

`i` = the interface index for the NIC that you want the traffic to use.

Add `-p` to the route add command if you want the route to be persistend after a system restart.

Comment: How to do that ?

Comment: @AshOoO I updated my answer with a sample `route add` command. You will have to fill in the blanks for your environment since you didn't provide any details.

Comment: I know the add route command but what I need to know which Ip,netmask or gateway to use with

use the ip,netmask and gateway for the first interface then use the metric and the interface index for the second interface !!

Comment: Thank you :) for your help .. Now please review my orginal post again after clearing it more